# How do I calculate expression inside an LWC iterator?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript-controller

I have an iterator rendering a list, simplified markup shown below:

```
<template for:each={cells} for:item="cell">
      <template lwc:if={showOption1}>
            ...
      </template>
      <template lwc:if={showOption2}>
            ...
      </template>
</template>
```

Inside that iterator I have two templates that are conditionally rendered. What I cant figure out is how do I calculate the value of showOption1 and showOption2 if they are dependent on information stored in the iterator item 'cell'.

So, for each iteration of item cell, how do I calculate 'showOption1' and 'showOption2' in the js controller, to determine a true or false for these expressions?

Any pointers appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the JS controller you have to extend the `cell` object adding new boolean properties that evaluate to `true` when `showOptionN` evaluates to `true`.

I.E. let's say you retrieve a list of accounts from apex and you should show option1 when AnnualRevenue is greater than 1000 and option2 when it's a negative value, your JS code would look like this:

```js
cells = [];

fetchAccounts() {
    getAccount() // call the apex method
        .then((accounts) => { // handle the result
            this.cells = accounts.map((account) => {
                return {
                    ...account,
                    showOption1: account.AnnualRevenue > 1000,
                    showOption2: account.AnnualRevenue < 0
                }
            });
        }) 
        .catch((error) => {
            // handle the error
        })
}
```

Then the HTML code would look like:

```html
<template for:each={cells} for:item="cell">
      <template lwc:if={cell.showOption1}>
            ...
      </template>
      <template lwc:if={cell.showOption2}>
            ...
      </template>
</template>
```

Comment: Ahh ok. that makes sense. I was going in circles thinking I'd missed something about how to manage the expressions.  Thanks so much for taking the time to include a coded solution describing your answer.

Comment: @CloudHugger You're welcome, glad I could help!